# adding a click function to button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a delete button on a table and a jquery on click eventlistener for the button.
here is the code

```
$(".delbtn").click(function () { 
    var count = 0;
    var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr'); 
    var $columns = $row.find('td'); 

    var values = ""; 

    jQuery.each($columns, function(i, item) { 
        if( count == 0 ){delFund = item.innerHTML}
        if( count == 1) {delOrg  = item.innerHTML}
        if( count == 2) {stat = item.innerHTML }    
        count++
    }); 

//the below lines of codes would display how to show values on a browser like 
// firefox or chrome.
//console.log(delFund, delOrg);


    $(this).closest("tr").fadeTo(500, 0, function () {  
        $(this).remove(); 
    }); 


//update the item on the database table for deletion.
  $.ajax({type: "POST",
          url: "dbfunctions.jsp",  
          data: {TYPE:'D', fundval: delFund, orgval: delOrg, tuidval:tuid, status:stat }}).done(function( msg )
          {  
            //alert(msg);
          });

});
```

This all works fine,my problem is that i query a database which i then used to update the html table with this data and I add an new button to the last row on the table. However the button does not respond when i click it. I believe is because there has not been an event listener attached to it. So my my question is how can I update the button so that the event listener that i have already added to all the previous buttons also gets attached to the new dynamically generated button?

here is the code snippet of how i add the item to the end of my table.

```
$("#thisTable > tbody").append( 
                                        "<tr><td>"+thisfund.value+"</td>"+
                                        "<td>"+thisorg.value+"</td>"+
                                        "<td>"+'PENDING ACCESS'+"</td>" +
                                        "<td>"+"<a class='delbtn' href='#'>X</a>"+"</td></tr>");
        thisfund.value = "";// set the input boxes back to null
            thisorg.value  = "";

          });
```

Comment: You should look into `$.delegate` http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: `delegate()` (not $.delegate) is deprecated. You should look into [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @wnwall: `.on()` for jquery >= 1.7

Comment: Ah, there is no note on the page referenced that `delegate` is deprecated, although there is a note on the `live` page.

Comment: @wnwall you're right, my bad. It's not recommended anymore though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this man:

API: http://api.jquery.com/on/

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object.

Any event names can be used for the events argument. jQuery will pass through the browser's standard JavaScript event types, calling the handler function when the browser generates events due to user actions such as click.

In your case even though the new tr with `class='delbtn'` the `.on` event will take it over.

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
$(document).on('click','.delbtn',function () { 
    var count = 0;
    var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr'); 
    var $columns = $row.find('td'); 

    var values = ""; 

    jQuery.each($columns, function(i, item) { 
        if( count == 0 ){delFund = item.innerHTML}
        if( count == 1) {delOrg  = item.innerHTML}
        if( count == 2) {stat = item.innerHTML }    
        count++
    });
```

Comment: tats i dont get it you are basically telling me i have to bind the button and rewrite the function all over?... Which is what im not trying to do.

Comment: @Miguel Hiya, Nopes - I am using your function only difference is attaching the **Click** event using `.on` API `:)` i.e. only change is this `$(document).on('click','.delbtn',function () { ...` **rest** all is bit of extra explanation if you keen, hope this helps

Comment: gotcha! you are the man! thanks for pointing me in the right direction thats exaclty what i was stuck on! I truly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The click event on the .delbtn is not a live event and is not applied to the newly appended elements.

Depending the JQuery version you are using you can use one of the following to add a live event.

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: Thanks for responding JB. This is also very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(newButton).bind('click',function(){...})
```